# Memory Leaks in app

Tags: ios, performance, memory

These are memory leaks. Can you please tell me how to solve these? The app crashes because of issues.

```
Leaked Object   #   Address Size    Responsible Library Responsible Frame
Malloc 16 Bytes 1   0x169eea00  16 Bytes    SystemConfiguration SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress
Malloc 16 Bytes 1   0x155c2100  16 Bytes    SystemConfiguration SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress
Malloc 16 Bytes 1   0x16a54770  16 Bytes    SystemConfiguration SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress
_NSUndoStack    1   0x155de700  32 Bytes    Foundation  -[NSUndoManager init]
SCNetworkReachability   1   0x16a626c0  464 Bytes   SystemConfiguration __SCNetworkReachabilityCreatePrivate
SCNetworkReachability   1   0x16914f40  464 Bytes   SystemConfiguration __SCNetworkReachabilityCreatePrivate
_UITextUndoManager  1   0x156f52a0  48 Bytes    UIKit   -[UITextInputController undoManager]
Malloc 16 Bytes 1   0x1697ef40  16 Bytes    SystemConfiguration SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress
Malloc 16 Bytes 1   0x16a2e4a0  16 Bytes    SystemConfiguration SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress
Malloc 16 Bytes 1   0x156007b0  16 Bytes    SystemConfiguration SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress
SCNetworkReachability   1   0x16ace130  464 Bytes   SystemConfiguration __SCNetworkReachabilityCreatePrivate
NSArray 1   0x155d3990  16 Bytes    Foundation  -[NSUndoManager init]
SCNetworkReachability   2   < multiple >    928 Bytes   SystemConfiguration __SCNetworkReachabilityCreatePrivate
SCNetworkReachability   1   0x156eeaf0  464 Bytes   SystemConfiguration __SCNetworkReachabilityCreatePrivate
Malloc 16 Bytes 1   0x15516dd0  16 Bytes    SystemConfiguration SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress
SCNetworkReachability   2   < multiple >    928 Bytes   SystemConfiguration __SCNetworkReachabilityCreatePrivate
Malloc 16 Bytes 1   0x16961a80  16 Bytes    SystemConfiguration SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress
SCNetworkReachability   1   0x15516c00  464 Bytes   SystemConfiguration __SCNetworkReachabilityCreatePrivate
SCNetworkReachability   1   0x16abea20  464 Bytes   SystemConfiguration __SCNetworkReachabilityCreatePrivate
Malloc 16 Bytes 1   0x16a60fa0  16 Bytes    SystemConfiguration SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress
SCNetworkReachability   1   0x16ac9210  464 Bytes   SystemConfiguration __SCNetworkReachabilityCreatePrivate
SCNetworkReachability   1   0x156cb670  464 Bytes   SystemConfiguration __SCNetworkReachabilityCreatePrivate
SCNetworkReachability   1   0x16954490  464 Bytes   SystemConfiguration __SCNetworkReachabilityCreatePrivate
SCNetworkReachability   1   0x16a1f710  464 Bytes   SystemConfiguration __SCNetworkReachabilityCreatePrivate
Malloc 16 Bytes 1   0x16a1db40  16 Bytes    SystemConfiguration SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress
Malloc 16 Bytes 1   0x16961f90  16 Bytes    SystemConfiguration SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress
Malloc 16 Bytes 2   < multiple >    32 Bytes    SystemConfiguration SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress
SCNetworkReachability   1   0x16a5f9d0  464 Bytes   SystemConfiguration __SCNetworkReachabilityCreatePrivate
Malloc 16 Bytes 1   0x1697f2a0  16 Bytes    SystemConfiguration SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress
SCNetworkReachability   1   0x169911c0  464 Bytes   SystemConfiguration __SCNetworkReachabilityCreatePrivate
SCNetworkReachability   1   0x169cf6c0  464 Bytes   SystemConfiguration __SCNetworkReachabilityCreatePrivate
Malloc 16 Bytes 1   0x16a1dc60  16 Bytes    SystemConfiguration SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress
SCNetworkReachability   1   0x16960090  464 Bytes   SystemConfiguration __SCNetworkReachabilityCreatePrivate
SCNetworkReachability   1   0x16961dc0  464 Bytes   SystemConfiguration __SCNetworkReachabilityCreatePrivate
Malloc 16 Bytes 2   < multiple >    32 Bytes    SystemConfiguration SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress
Malloc 16 Bytes 1   0x156c9d50  16 Bytes    SystemConfiguration SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress
Malloc 16 Bytes 1   0x1699c6d0  16 Bytes    SystemConfiguration SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress
SCNetworkReachability   1   0x16a3be60  464 Bytes   SystemConfiguration __SCNetworkReachabilityCreatePrivate
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Search, research, reading documentations and previous posts about memory leaks?

Comment: I have figured memory leaks but unable to solve them

Comment: Have you enabled Zombie Objects?

Comment: NO i have not enabled

Comment: In xcode press cmd+shift+b and if there are memory leaks xcode will let u know. Else code leak(in correct logic) would be there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think there is something allocated in the file SCNetworkReachability (function SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress) . But is not so clear were from your log. Are you able to isolate the code where you use Reachability? Are you using ARC in your code?

Comment: Actually Iam using AFNetworking API to get Images from Server

Comment: Is the file SCNetworkReachability your own file or is the file from apple where you can understand the status of the network (wi-fi connected or not example). When you have this error? When you send or receive the images from the server?

Comment: Iam using AFNetworking to get and post calls from server and i used SDWEbimage to display images from web Url

Comment: Without to see the code is not easy to understand where is the problem. I can suggest to try to identify the portion of the code where you have the problem (wich row of code, which function and so), then try to create a small project with the same code and try to replicate the problem. Probably there is something wrong in some object allocation ore some zombie that can consume memory...

Comment: hai can anyone help me to solve memory leaks